# Can Istio map an non existing host to a given service on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, istio

2 questions for you guys.

I have a pod A trying to request a url called *foo* doing a GET on http://foo .
But the service foo does not exists in my K8 cluster instead I have a service called *fooX* that could do the job.
Is it possible to create an Istio configuration to route my call to foo to the fooX service ?

More generally we have a bunch of services calling other services and that get the service urls via environment variables, but the more service we have the more environment variable we have, it is not scalable. I hoped service mesh would help in the regard but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use K8S [ExternalName services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for that:

> An ExternalName service is a special case of service that does not have selectors. It does not define any ports or Endpoints. Rather, it serves as a way to return an alias to an external service residing outside the cluster.

While it was intended to define an alias to a service outside the cluster, it can be used to create aliases for the services inside the cluster as well. In your case, just define the following K8S Service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: fooX.prod.svc.CLUSTER
```

So when your apps will send requests to http://foo.prod.svc.CLUSTER, the requests will arrive http://fooX.prod.svc.CLUSTER.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is a pure K8s solution which works fine. Is there a way to do that with Istio routing manifests ? I am trying to understand the VirtualService configuration.

Comment: By the way I did not manage to make this work with Istio. I have change the Bookinfo.yaml to rename the service *reviews* into *reviewxx* and tried to find a way to redirect http call from the *productpage* calling *reviews* url into the reviewxx service but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, it is possible using a `ExternalService` (renamed `ServiceEntry` in 0.8.1). However, this comes with the caveat that the name you choose for the alias in the `ServiceEntry` be DNS resolvable for HTTP. Otherwise the DNS lookup will fail, and the connection will never make it to the proxy to be routed based on the `ServiceEntry`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll the previous response this is a pure K8s response it does not speak about ServiceEntry. But I tried combining the 2 solutions in order to create a DNS resolvable entry using K8s externalName service type and then route it istio ServiceEntry without any success at all. It seems istio does not like going through a K8s external service that in fact targets an internal one.